# Adding UIBarButtonItem to all Navigation View Controllers inside a UITabBarController programmatically

Tags: ios

The structure is as follows:

- View
- Tab Bar Controller

  - Navigation Controller

    - View Controller
  - Navigation Controller

    - View Controller
  - Navigation Controller

    - View Controller
  - Navigation Controller

    - View Controller
  - Navigation Controller

    - View Controller
  - Navigation Controller

    - View Controller

The above controllers have been initialised in interface builder.

What I'm trying to do is add a right `UIBarButtonItem` to each navigation controller but not having any success.

Here's what I've tried:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.view.opaque = NO;
    self.tabBarController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;

    NSArray *currentViewControllers = self.tabBarController.viewControllers;
    NSMutableArray *updatedViewControllers = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (int i=0; i<currentViewControllers.count; i++) {
        UINavigationController *tempNav = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];
        tempNav = [currentViewControllers objectAtIndex:i];
        UIBarButtonItem *dismissButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                          initWithTitle:@"Done"                                            
                                          style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                          target:self 
                                          action:@selector(dismissLibraryBrowser)];
        tempNav.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = dismissButton;
        [updatedViewControllers addObject:tempNav];
        [dismissButton release];
        [tempNav release];

        NSLog(@"Added controller number %d",i);
    }

    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithArray:updatedViewControllers];

    [self.view addSubview:tabBarController.view];
}
```

The code executes without any errors, but the button doesn't appear. I'm sure I've misunderstood something here. Would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: Did you check for the child views of navigation controller while selecting the tab items....

Comment: Why would I need to do that? I'm adding a button to the navigation controller only. Everything shows up fine, only the buttons are not added.

Comment: I see that from your code.. Still I am not in my MAC, so if you log the child views of Navigation Controller then we just can confirm that the button items are still exists or not ...

Comment: How did you manage to nest a `UITabBarController` inside a `UIViewController` in a nib?

Comment: @Paul.s I didn't! That was a mistake in the post, fixed now.

Comment: It still doesn't make sense that you are adding the `UITabBarController` to a view. It is normally the rootViewController. Where is the nib loaded? If you are targeting >= iOS 4 then you would create the `UITabBarController` and add it as the `rootViewController` of the main window

Comment: My `rootViewController` is a separate view controller. The `UITabBarController` is separate and is only needed at certain times.

Comment: The code you have posted suggest you are placing the `UITabBarController` inside another `UIViewController` as `UIViewController` has the method `viewDidLoad` not `UIView`

Comment: Yeah, my root view controller is view controller #1, and I also have view controller #2 (above) with a `UITabBarController` that is added only when needed. I'm still rather new to this so if you have suggestions on the correct way I should do this please do say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are over complicating things slightly with recreating viewControllers and temporary arrays. You just need to manipulate the objects loaded from the nib

```
[self.tabBarController.viewControllers enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UINavigationController *navigationController, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

    UIViewController *rootViewController = [navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

    UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButtonItem  = 
      [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done"                                            
                                       style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                      target:self 
                                      action:@selector(dismissLibraryBrowser)];

    rootViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButtonItem;

 }];
```

---

As for the structure of your app - the docs for [UITabBarController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) say

> When deploying a tab bar interface, you must install this view as the root of your window. Unlike other view controllers, a tab bar interface should never be installed as a child of another view controller.

So I would suggest having a look at restructuring some stuff, if you need it only occasionally why not consider presenting it modally?

Comment: Didn't think of that (modal view that is), I'll restructure it then. And thanks for your solution!

Comment: The `dismissLibraryBrowser` function simple dismisses the modal view controller with `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`. Whilst this works fine on the first view controller of every tab, it doesn't work in any of additional pushed view controllers in that tab. Any thoughts?