# use the same UINavigationBar object in all children views

Tags: ios5, uinavigationcontroller, xcode4.2, storyboard, uinavigationbar

hi im developing an ios aplication and the ui was desigbed using the storyboard (first time using it) so i have the folowing:

- entry point: navigation Controller
- rootView view controller (push to many other view some of one are UITableView)
- and then i programatically push (in some controllers) a view loaded from a nib (no problem on this)

each controller has a defined title.

what i want to do is put a rigth button on the nav bar of all view controller so i can push (programatically) to another controller (wish is in a nib, but i coul move it to the SB whit no problem)

i have tried:

- using a custom class and an nib file but i get the same uncustumised nav bar
- overwriting initWithCoder so i can redirect it to de nib file but get an infinite loop (StakOverflow, yay!)
- using a second class to avoid the infinite loop but get an exception:

  > Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'This coder requires that replaced objects be returned from initWithCoder:
- add the button manually in the init method of the navbar class, no efect
- replace the navigation bar in the navigation controller  initWithCoder, no efect
- same but in the viewDidLoad method of the navigation controller, no efect
- same but in the rootView Controller, no efect

the code i was using was this (and a few variations):

```
UIBarButtonItem *BTN = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
      initWithImage:[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"img.png"] 
      style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
      target:self 
      action:@selector(pushView)];

[[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:BTN];
```

is ther any way that i can archive this, or should i do it manually view per view?

--thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you would need to do in each view controller for it's `navigationItem` property. But you can make it easier by creating a `category` on `UIBarButtonItem` class which will have a method configuring and returning the button you need everywhere.
So you only need to invoke that category's method and no need to write same code everywhere.

Here are some similar posts:

[Adding same button to all view controllers in UINavigationController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389094/adding-same-button-to-all-view-controllers-in-uinavigationcontroller)

[Adding UIBarButtonItem to all Navigation View Controllers inside a UITabBarController programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158059/adding-uibarbuttonitem-to-all-navigation-view-controllers-inside-a-uitabbarcontr)