# how to set background image for "More" navigation controller of a UITabBarController in ios 6

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I want to change the background image of More Navigation controller.I googled and tried with below code.

[image: here is the customize tab bar or more navigation controller image.]

I tried with below code but[image: !![it over rides the tableview and looks like below image]`][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJoS0.png)

```
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.delegate=self;
tabBarController.moreNavigationController.delegate = self;


if ([tabBarController.moreNavigationController.topViewController.view isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]])
{
    UIView* newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,367)];

    UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]];
    imageView.opaque = NO;
    imageView.alpha = 0.4;
    [newView addSubview:imageView];

    tabBarController.moreNavigationController.topViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    tabBarController.moreNavigationController.topViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,367);
    //[newView addSubview:tabBarController.moreNavigationController.view];
[newView addSubview:tabBarController.moreNavigationController.topViewController.view];
    tabBarController.moreNavigationController.topViewController.view = newView;
}
```

`][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJoS0.png)

Any one suggest where i am going wrong will be appreciated

"Thanks"

Comment: try here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150788/customize-the-more-uibarbuttonitem-in-uitabbar

Comment: try that solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158059/adding-uibarbuttonitem-to-all-navigation-view-controllers-inside-a-uitabbarcontr

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692517/change-navigation-bar-background-image-on-each-navigation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[tabBarController.moreNavigationController.topViewController.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]]];